# Proof of the Bonferonni inequalities

Tags: probability

It is to be shown that for a collection of finite sets, $S_1, S_2 .... S_n$, for each k in range $1 \leq k \leq n $ there we have that for $k$ even:

$$ 
\sum_{J \subseteq \{ 1, \ldots, n \}, 1 \leq |J| \leq k} (-1)^{|J|-1} \left | \bigcap_{i \in J} S_{i} \right| \leq \left| \bigcup_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}} S_{i} \right|
$$

and for each odd $k$ we have

$$ \sum_{J \subseteq \{ 1, \ldots, n \}, 1 \leq |J| \leq k} (-1)^{|J|-1} \left | \bigcap_{i \in J} S_{i} \right| \geq \left| \bigcup_{i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}} S_{i} \right|$$

I have seen many proofs particularly
https://planetmath.org/proofofbonferroniinequalities. However, it seems like they are dealing with are dealing with integration. Is this possible with finite sets? Is there a difference in terms of the proof with finite sets?

I have been trying to find the original proof by Bonferroni in Italian, but I have been unable to find it. Any help in this direction that doesn't require.

Comment: Don't let the integral fool you. Those integrals can be thought as merely sums where you are dealing with the "Counting measure".

Answer (score 1):

I'll write my version of proving Beferonni's inequality for both odd and even cases (under context of probability $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$): if $A_i\in\mathcal{A}$ is a sequence of events, then
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)\ge\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)-\sum_{i<j}P(A_i\cap A_j)$$
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)-\sum_{i<j}P(A_i\cap A_j)+\sum_{i<j<k}P(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)$$

For any $x\in\Omega$, claim that $$\chi_{x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i}\ge\sum_{i}\chi_{x\in A_i}-\sum_{i<j}\chi_{x\in A_i\cap A_j}$$

Indeed, if $x$ is exactly $m$ sets of $A_i$'s, for $m=0$ it's the trivial case; for $m\ge 1$, $1\ge m-\binom{m}{2}$ holds (Why?). Then integrate the above identity w.r.t. the probabbility measure to get the result.

For the other case, stop the binomial expansion at third order, and use the same reasoning. For extension to higher order cases, it will be the same idea. Hope this helps.